# When to use specifically the niebloid std::ranges::construct_at instead of std::construct_at?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, std-ranges, range-v3

In the situation that we have two choices of exactly the same functionality.
One is a niebloid, the other is a function.

Are there any guidelines for this in general?

- `std::construct_at` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at
- `std::ranges::construct_at` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/ranges/construct_at

Comment: Related https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/m27rsw/rangesconstruct_at_and_stdconstruct_at/

Comment: Perhaps for consistency, if you later intend to use `ranges::destroy_at`.